# Access Forbidden Error 403 -- How Can I Create Alias to Apache Xampp on Mac

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, alias

I know this is not a new question here. Some people has asked the same question before and I have tried all their solutions, but still can not solve the issue.

I have used MAMP before.  I installed it when I developed web sites 5 years ago. Then, I lately tried to use but alias didn't work and got access forbidden Error 403.

I installed the MAMP many years ago, and wanted to try XAMPP, so I removed MAMP and installed XAMPP on my mac with MacOS Big Sur 11.7.8.  But, I still get Access Forbidden Error 403.

Here is what I have done:

My project working directory is /Users/mac3/Documents/proj. XAMPP is installed in /Applications/XAMPP directory.

The appache document root directory is Applications/XAMPP/htdoc. I created alias 'proj' in htdoc directory -- I tried three different methods: 1.  in finder, click on the directory and right click and selected "Make Alias",  2. in htdoc directory run ln -s proj "/Users/mac3/Documents/proj", 3. Alias /proj "Users/mac3/Documents/proj"

I created httpd-project.conf file to set access privilege and write in the file:

```
<Directory /Users/mac3/Documents/proj>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</Directory>

Alias /www "/Users/sam-mba-3/Documents/proj"
```

I added a line below in apache httpd.conf file which is under /Applications/XAMPP/etc

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-project.conf
```

I have spent a few days and had no luck.

I want to use alias (e.g. localhost/) instead of placing project holder under document root holder,htdocs. But, Access Forbidden! Error 403 occurs.